# how to display div element and s:textfield in same line

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts

I have `<s:textfield>` and a div elements I want to display both in same line how can I do this.

```
<s:textfield key="dimProgram.name" required="true" maxlength="128" />
<div class="hide prohramNameCheck" id="floatingBarsG">
  <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_01"></div>
  <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_02"></div>
  <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_03"></div>
  <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_04"></div>
  <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_05"></div>
  <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_06"></div><
  <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_07"></div><
  <div class="blockG" id="rotateG_08"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Div takes on Complete line, it will not work directly, but can be done with table or with css aligning.
See the code snippet below, Similarly you can adjust to your need.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">Image 1</div>
    <div class="div2">Image 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.container {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    margin: auto;   
    width: 304px;
}

div.div1 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

div.div2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azXMN/

Comment: other way round you could have done it using setting 'div style to inline'